# Python - How to show graph in Visual Studio Code itself?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

When I try to run this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

I see the result in a new window.

Is there any way to see the result graphs in the Visual Studio Code itself directly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Yes, if you use notebook interface. Basically, install Python Extension Pack, it includes Jupyter extension, put your code in the editor, put `#%%` at the top of your code, you'll get `Run cell` clickable, click it, and you'll get result in the other window

[image]

Here is the link to the extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.jupyter

**UPDATE**

Ok, apparently Microsoft hired Don Jayamanne and he's working on Python and Jupyter for VS Code. And last month they (MS) improved their python extension to support Jupyter notebooks right in the Visual Code together with .ipynb import and export. Get extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) and check [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2018/11/08/data-science-with-python-in-visual-studio-code/) how to use it with Jupyter notebooks.

**UPDATE II**

Another one is Neuron, under development, but looks nice - again, notebooks in VS Code, with graphs, markdown etc. Get it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neuron.neuron-IPE)

**UPDATE III**

Using interactive matplotlib graphs works as well in VS Code, check https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/ for details

Comment: Thanks! I finally made it work ( I don't know how though :)

Comment: Well, it's not as good actually. For some reason this extension ignores the code below. How would I fix it?UPD: Oh I see. It now use the Results window for ALL outputs. So it works!

Comment: @mimic Yes, it is a notebook interface. Frankly, I don't use it much, just to make graph or two, otherwise Jupyter lab is quite superior to work with notebooks

Comment: I don't use Jupyter interface because it doesn't allow to debug.

Comment: @mimic looks for PixieDust

Comment: neuron doesnt work because you cant specify your python version if youre using conda etc.

Comment: It requires jupyter notebook. Notebooks are not designed for development. I have multiple files and classes and do not want to use notebooks at all. I just want to see the plot result. Just like Matlab and Spyder.

Answer (score 40):

Instead of using a Jupyter notebook you can use Visual Studio Code in Interactive mode. It is similar to a notebook in many ways, as it splits your code into cells that can be run individually. One advantage over notebooks is that this remains a normal .py file. Spyder IDE also has this feature.

You can split your code into cells using `# %%` as in this example. Running code this way, Visual Studio Code opens an Interactive pane that displays the plots inline.

```
# %%
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# %% 
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 1001)))
plt.show()
```

Comment: This has the added benefit of being easily run as a straight python file. +1!

Comment: Yes, exactly. For me it always seems more useful than a notebook.

Comment: Notebooks are good for story telling. They are not production tools. Very inefficient when you have multiple files and many more.

Comment: @Ash very true.

Answer (score 7):

If you right-click on your code and choose `"Run Current File in Interactive Window"` it will open a new interactive pane and run the code there instead of in the standard terminal pane.

This has the advantage that it shows images inline but also allows you to code using a .py file instead of a notebook.

To make things easier, in my settings I have set up <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut to this run option.

I find this move convenient than my previous answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's no use installing some extra packs or applying `#%%` stuff nowadays . If you don't see any graph on cell execution but only text kinda `<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>` you might need to change mime-type for output:

1. Click `...` (More Actions...) on the upper left corner of the output (right under the cell).
2. Choose `Change presentation`.
3. Then choose the option `image/png` or any other you like (seems like you have `text/plain` at the moment) in `Select mimetype to render for current output` menu.

Works for Win 11 and Ubuntu VS Code with the only default Python extension and `matplotlib` library installed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to use plots in Visual Studio Code is with Juypiter notebooks. You need to install the official Microsoft Python plugin `ms-python.python`.

Once installed, you may open an existing notebook or create one in the command palette with

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select `Python: Create Blank New Jupyter Notebook`

Docs: [Create or open a Jupyter Notebook](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_create-or-open-a-jupyter-notebook)

**Visualizing Plots**

Pandas example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([2,5,67,2,3,5,23,124])
df.hist()
```

To execute, click on the green play icon or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

From the docs:

> The Plot Viewer gives you the ability to work more deeply with your plots. In the viewer you can pan, zoom, and navigate plots in the current session. You can also export plots to PDF, SVG, and PNG formats.
>
> Within the Notebook Editor window, double-click any plot to open it in the viewer, or select the plot viewer button on the upper left corner of the plot (visible on hover).

[Read more about using Jupyter in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_plot-viewer)

Answer (score -2):

Add this to the top of your code -

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: That works in Jupyter or Spyder. Not "out of the box" in VSCode. An extension is still needed as per the accepted answer.