# Is there any way to show figures in VScode remote ssh (windows)

Tags: python, ssh, visual-studio-code

vscode was installed in my windows computer, I use ssh remote service
and when I tried to plot a figure, the figure just did not show up.
e.g.,
the code as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

when I run the code in the remote ssh, the figure didn't show up.
(ps, the code works in my local computer)

Comment: How did you call SSH? What is the matplotlib backend on the remote machine? I don't think that the question has anything to do with VSCode.

Comment: i have tried ssh by using ss username@ip and ssh -XY username@ip, but both of them don't work. Also, I used xshell, which need xmanager to show figures, it works in remote machine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes its completely possible, but it requires the x11 Forwarding option.
In your ssh config file, add "ForwardX11 Yes"

```
Host myHost
  Hostname 192.168.1.1
  ForwardX11 Yes
```

Now the tricky part: the remote computer has to allow the forwarding (usually disabled by default).
On the remote host, go to the sshd_config file (usual location is /etc/ssh/sshd_config)
And make sure that the option

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

is present and that its NOT commented out.

Now whenever you ssh into that host, you should be able to run any graphical application from your windows computer

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't work for me even though i tried "ForwardAgent yes, ForwardX11Trusted yes" too, and "ssh ... -XY" as well.

Comment: Do you receive any error message when running "ssh -X host"? You should see a message like "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0" if the X forwarding failed

Comment: thanks for a quick reply, I didn't receive any error message,.

Comment: For Python code, I found an alternative way to show figures by adding "# %%" at the top of the code, and then one can see "Run cell" button, click it, the figure will show up at the right side of the window. see the link for those who need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992300/how-to-show-graph-in-visual-studio-code-itself

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem so I created a library to solve this here https://pypi.org/project/remote-plot/.

It doesn't require X11 forwarding / having a display.

It uses the exact same API as matplotlib (and actually uses matplotlib to plot stuff), but it renders the plots in a web browser which you can view from your local machine.

Install by:

```
pip install remote_plot
```

And then run in python like this:

```
from remote_plot import plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

By default it opens the rendering on port 8000 but you can modify this easily. If you are connecting via ssh, don't forget to forward the port by adding the following flag to your ssh command:

```
ssh YOUR_USER_NAME@YOUR_MACHINE_IP -L 8000:localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options (which I think require the `Jupyter` extension to be installed remotely...someone correct me if I'm wrong and I'll edit this answer).

**Option 1:** *Display figures generated by a .py file*

- Using `VScode` with the `Remote - SSH` extension to connect to a remote server, you can right-click in the file text area and select `Run Current File in Interactive Window`.  This will show plots in what looks to me like a `iPython` or `jupyter notebook` type window.

For example, if you have `basic_plot.py` with the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [i for i in range(100)]
y = [10*i for i in x]
plt.plot(x,y, '-x')
```

With `basic_plot.py` open in `VScode` for editing, right-click & select `Run Current File in Interactive Window`.  This will open a window like below
[image]

**Option 2:** *Display pyplot figures by writing code in iypthon/jupyter notebook style interactive window*

- Open the `VScode` command palatte (either via the `View` menu or `Ctrl+Shift+P').
- Type "Create Interactive Window" in the command palette.
- Select "Jupyter: Create Interactive Window".
- An interactive window (like in the pic from option 1 above) will appear where you can write and execute
  python code like in ipython or jupyter notebook.