# How to make Plotly graph animated working

Tags: python, animation, graph, plotly

Hi I am trying to use Plotly v4.6. Everything is working fine. I can see all graphs except when I tried to replicate the animated graph from the website:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])
```

I can see the graph but no animation when I click on the run button or try to change the date on the bar. I try to implement others examples. Same result.

I have no error message. Nothing seems to be wrong. 
I am working on VSCode 1.43.2

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I tested this code on my jupyter and it works.
You need to make plotly **offline**
It opens another tab and show animation. Another thing is you need to use plot to render it in anaconda.

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot

df = px.data.gapminder()
fig=px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])
plot(fig)
```

Comment: Your solution worked even in vscode. it open a new safari page. Thanks for this answer. But do you have an idea why it was not working previously ? Why can I have my animated graph inside my vscode as I anticipated ? Is it a bug inside Plotly ? Vscode ?

Comment: @Jacques I am happy that it helped you. You must have plotly account in order to render graph as online, otherwise you should make it offline to illustrate it. The only goal of having a plotly account is to host the graphs in your plotly account.

Plotly Offline allows you to build graphs offline and save them locally. Instead of saving the graphs to a server, your data and graphs will remain in your local system. If it could help please accept that answer and the next ones can find the best solution quickly.

Comment: You can refer to this link: https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/?utm_source=mailchimp-jan-2015&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=generalemail-jan2015&utm_term=bubble-chart

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of additional installation steps: https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support-python-35

or follow:

https://plotly.com/python/troubleshooting/

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder() 

px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", size=”pop”, size_max=60, color="continent", hover_name="country", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country", log_x=True, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90], labels=dict(pop=”Population”, gdpPercap=”GDP per Capita”, lifeExp=”Life Expectancy”) )
```

Or please check:
[How to show graph in Visual Studio Code itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992300/how-to-show-graph-in-visual-studio-code-itself)

> Install Python Extension Pack, it includes Jupyter extension, put your
>   code in the editor, put #%% at the top of your code, you'll get Run
>   cell clickable, click it, and you'll get result in the other window.

For Visual Studio use Neuron:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neuron.neuron-IPE

Comment: I already see this. I am not using Jupyterlab But vscode. So do I need to follow all the installation procedure ? 
I just did : Conda install Plotly

Comment: Yes, I think the best way is to use anaconda package: https://www.anaconda.com/

Comment: That's what I did ! and it works except animation :((

Comment: here https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support-python-35 they say that I just need to : conda install -c plotly plotly=4.6.0. The rest is for Jupyter and jupyterLab and I am using vscode

Comment: I already follow https://plotly.com/python/troubleshooting/ and desinstall Plotly and reinstall it. But nothing change

Comment: Could you download anaconda, it has Jupyter. And all will work.

Comment: Try notebooks in VS Code, with graphs, markdown etc: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neuron.neuron-IPE

Comment: I already have Anaconda installed. I tried with jupyter but I have nothing. Nothing happens on the screen whereas with vscode I had a graph.

Comment: @Jacques I updated my answer and also wrote on my comment. For usig vs code please use neuron https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992300/how-to-show-graph-in-visual-studio-code-itself

Comment: In vscode I tried with python code and jupyter integrated inside vscode. I have the graph but no animation at all.

Comment: I also tried all examples from plotly website. Everything is working (graph with buttons for example) except examples from here : https://plotly.com/python/animations/

Comment: @Jacques I sent another answer which is proper for Jupyter, please select the answer as accepted if it works. Just it might be the twice press run button in Jupyter and there is a play button which you need to press to show animation.