# Plotly Express choropleth map not showing in visual studio code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-visualization, plotly-express

Below shown the syntax used to get a map visualized and plotted from Plotly Express - choropleth from a "csv" DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import plotly.express as px


df = "//location.csv"

fig = px.choropleth(data_frame = df,
                    locations= df["location"],
                    locationmode='country names',
                    color=df["location"],
                    hover_name=df["location"],
                    title = "Location Data",
                    color_continuous_scale = px.colors.sequential.Oranges)
 
 
fig["layout"].pop("updatemenus")
fig.show()
```

However, when I use the above syntax on the Visual Studio Code Jupyter Notebook, the map does not get visualized and plotted. Which is shown as below,

[image]

But when I run the same code on the Anaconda Jupyter Notebook, I do get the map visualized and plotted as shown below,

[image]

Why isn't the map not getting visualized and plotted on VS code, and is there any way to resolve this issue on VS code?

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in this question because I usually work with jypyterLab. I ran it based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176493/how-to-make-plotly-graph-animated-working), and when I ran it in vscode, it displayed correctly in my default browser. The code I ran was based on the code in the official reference.

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")
fig = px.choropleth(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                    color="lifeExp", # lifeExp is a column of gapminder
                    hover_name="country", # column to add to hover information
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)
# fig.show()
plot(fig)
```

[image]