# Why am I getting array instead of vector size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to get a vector size(46). But I getting array. The dataset that I used is Reuters.

The place where I print NN predictions is the last lines of code.

Code:

```
from keras.datasets import reuters
from keras import models, layers, losses
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=10000)

word_index = reuters.get_word_index()
reverse_word_index = dict([(value, key) for (key, value) in word_index.items()])
decoded_newswire = ' '.join([reverse_word_index.get(i - 3, '?') for i in train_data[0]])

def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequences in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequences] = 1.
    return results

x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)

one_hot_train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
one_hot_test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
            metrics=['accuracy'])

x_val = x_train[:1000]
partial_x_train = x_train[1000:]

y_val = one_hot_train_labels[:1000]
partial_y_train = one_hot_train_labels[1000:]

history = model.fit(partial_x_train,
                    partial_y_train,
                    epochs=9, 
                    batch_size=128, 
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

predictions = model.predict(x_test)

predictions[0].shape
print(predictions)
```

Output:

```
# WHY?                
[[4.2501447e-06 1.9825067e-07 2.3206076e-07 ... 2.1613120e-07
  9.8317461e-09 1.3596014e-07]
 [1.6055314e-02 1.4951903e-01 1.4057434e-04 ... 1.1199807e-04
  1.8230558e-06 2.4111385e-03]
 [7.8554759e-03 6.6994888e-01 1.6705523e-03 ... 4.0704478e-04
  2.4865860e-05 7.2334736e-04]
 ...
 [2.9577111e-06 9.5703072e-06 3.2641565e-05 ... 2.3492355e-06
  1.8574113e-06 3.1159422e-07]
 [1.7232201e-03 1.7063649e-01 1.5664790e-02 ... 4.8910693e-04
  4.2799808e-04 1.0207186e-03]
 [1.7965600e-04 6.5334785e-01 7.2387634e-03 ... 9.2276223e-06
  1.9617393e-05 1.7480283e-05]]
```

Comment: I think you need to explain better what you are getting and what you want to get.

Comment: What is the result of `predictions[0].shape` (meaningless to include it in the posted code without its output, right)? Isn't it 46?

Comment: I want to get in print 46, but I getting array. predictions[0].shape --> 46

Comment: So again, that looks correct? You expect 46 and 46 is printed. I do not see what is the problem.

Comment: You get an array of 46D-vectors as elements, each element (46D-vector) of the array corresponding to one sample of your `x_test`. `print(predictions)` is **not** expected to produce one 46D-vector.

Comment: Please do not repeat the same info again and again; read the suggested explanations first. Each *one* of your `predictions` is a 46-element vector, but the whole of `predictions` is not expected to be a 46-element vector.

Comment: Okay, I read in the book and saw this example. This example had output (46,), but I got an array in logs. I didn't understand. But now, u explained me. Thank u!

Comment: Your question is too vague to be useful to other people, and Stack Overflow is **not** a forum.

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422410/standard-implementation-of-vectorize-sequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got result that was need for me. I found him in another question from Stack Overflow:
[How to show graph in Visual Studio Code itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992300/how-to-show-graph-in-visual-studio-code-itself)

Use `#%%` for creating cells in that you will run independent fragments of code. It seems like *Python Shell*(this is Jupyter Notebook that I love).

[Result that I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFGEm.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj1XI.png)