# Figure is not shown on screen

Tags: visual-studio, matplotlib

The figure is not shown on screen.
I import matplotlib and try to plot a figure but nothing happens. I also get no error.

This is the program that I use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,20,21)
plt.plot(x)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show graph in Visual Studio Code itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992300/how-to-show-graph-in-visual-studio-code-itself)

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the function

```
plt.show()
```

to render a figure.

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.linspace(0,20,21) 
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```