# Using a devcontainer in VS Code, how can I display matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm running an Ubuntu devcontainer inside VS Code. However, when I run a python script that creates a plot, the plot doesn't show up anywhere, even when using `matplotlib.pyplot.show()`. My guess is that the devcontainer just doesn't have any way of displaying it. My workaround right now is to save the plot using `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()`, but that's not great when I just want to check something quickly.

Does anyone know how to see the plots created inside the devcontainer?

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# random data
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.sin(np.pi * x)

# try plotting
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: have you checked first answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992300/python-how-to-show-graph-in-visual-studio-code-itself?

Comment: Yes I have, it gives me this error:
```
Running cells with 'Python 3.9.10 ('gp')' requires ipykernel package.
Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment. 
Command: 'conda install -n gp ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall'
```
But the package is already installed in this conda environment...

Comment: what is the version of installed ipykernel?

Comment: If you run the source code directly, do you have any feedback? Was there a mistake or no response? I just did a replay and found that it would take a few seconds for a new window to appear.

Comment: @MingJie there was just no response. When I use VS code without a devcontainer, the plot window appears with ```plt.show()```, no problems.

@be_real it's 5.5.5

Comment: Is it feasible to reinstall Python extensions? Or reduce the extension to a stable version

Comment: @S.U. any success with this? I ran into the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Lazor, no unfortunately not. I'm just saving every plot as a pdf now as I have to do that anyway. Then I can just view the pdf using the vscode-pdf extension.