# Pandas doens't show scatter matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I don't see a scatter matrix if I run the following code in Visual Studio Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=\['A','B','C','D'\])
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2)
```

There is also no error message in the command line.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `columns=\['A','B','C','D'\]` is not correct syntax. Please edit the question (and your code) with `columns=['A','B','C','D']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want scatter matrix in question title but you use plot in code. Will you try this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2)
```

if you still don't see scatter matrix,
according to @medium-dimensional's suggestion you have to import **pyplot**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But I still don't see scatter matrix.

Comment: Which ide are you using?

Comment: @Clegane Since the OP is not using Jupyter Notebook/Lab, the plot won't show up directly. Please import `matplotlib.pyplot` and add `plt.show` once the matrix is drawn.

Comment: I'm using spyder and it shows up when I run the above codes.

Comment: I'm using VSCode. I tried to run this code in Pycharm, even in Jupyter, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please try what I have suggested in this thread?

Comment: Can you take a look at the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992300/python-how-to-show-graph-in-visual-studio-code-itself)

Comment: @medium-dimensional Thank you. Thank you everyone. `matplotlib.pyplot` and `pyplot.show()`  is solution of my problem.